# Request for assistance with re-opening a question I closed myself?

Tags: discussion

I've done something very silly.

1. Posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41113325/is-it-possible-to-commit-to-a-git-branch-without-first-checking-it-out).
2. Convinced myself that it was a duplicate and closed it.
3. Wrote an answer and prepared to post it to the "original" question.
4. Realized that the answer wasn't appropriate for the original question.
5. Trying to re-open my own original question.

**Could I please get some help with re-opening it?**

Side Note: It is curious that I can unilaterally close my own question, but it takes a multilateral effort to reopen it.

Comment: Was it that urgent that you needed to come to Meta with it? Why not wait like everyone else and have it go through the Reopen queue?

Comment: @Stijn, It wasn't a matter of urgency but more of explanation. I figured that people in the reopen queue would be confused by the fact that I had performed all the previous actions myself and choose to not act because they were unclear about my intentions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is now re-opened as I posted an request in the SOCVR room [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/34716372#34716372).

From their [FAQ](http://socvr.org/)

> However the room now acts pro-actively by issuing [cv-pls] requests, reopen voting, tag cleanup, burnination efforts, editing, coaching/commenting, delete voting, and feeding the roomba.

The regulars there are happy to help when they see fit.